# Media projection taking screenshots every second (or half a second)

Tags: java, android, screenshot, android-mediaprojection

Looking at [this](https://github.com/mtsahakis/MediaProjectionDemo/blob/master/src/com/mtsahakis/mediaprojectiondemo/ScreenCaptureImageActivity.java) example of **Media projection** taking **screenshots** I have noticed that screenshoting is not regular. For example, for each screenshot in a row it took this many miliseconds:

```
174
155
149
1000
998
2014
415
1606
2859
...
```

My question is: can I force *onImageAvailable* to take screenshots every certain amount of time? I need to use media projection since I will screenshot outside of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not regular because a screenshot is taken only if a new frame is available (something has changed on the screen). As far as I know it is not possible to take screenshots at regular intervals using Media Projection.

Answer (score 0):

For limiting how often screenshots are taken, use `Thread.sleep` after processing the image.

However, you need to execute some sort of trigger so that there is always an image available when `reader.acquireLatestImage()` is executed. Something like the screen changing will trigger a new frame, but there are other things that trigger a new frame without changing the screen, such as pressing the home button or creating an invisible toast notification (there are probably more but I can't find any right now). You can test them by charging your phone to 100%, having it on airplane mode, closing all other programs, and writing to Logcat.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
toast.getView().setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
toast.show();
image = reader.acquireLatestImage();
```

Because of how Toast notifications can't have their duration changed, the above code only works well using 1000 ms intervals or longer.